# devops-rest APi - $expand not working for "Work Items - Get Work Items Batch"

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to access some data from selected work items. 

Below is my working code.

```
function postApiData(ApiUrl, responseBody, token) {
            var res = '';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: ApiUrl,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(responseBody),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + _token));
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                res = data;
            });
        return res;
    };

 var d = {
                    "ids": itemlist,
                    "fields": ["System.Id", "System.WorkItemType", "System.Title", "System.AssignedTo", "System.State", "System.Tags", "cust.PID", "cust.Product", "cust.ReleasedToProduction"]
                };
                var itemdata = postApiData('https://dev.azure.com/COMP/products/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?$expand=relations&api-version=5.1', d, '');
```

However, $expand is not working here to get relations. query gives the result and always ignores $expand.

I have also tried to pass $expand in request body, but it is also not working.  Can anyone please guide here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `expand` parameter can not be used with the `fields` parameter if the `expand` value is `relations`.

You could execute this api with your request body in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You will get the clearly message that why you can not apply it.

[image]

---

To use your API, if you specify the `fields` in the request body, then `expand` should not be used any more, and vice versa. This is as designed, and it has been **hardcoded** into our scripts. We do not allow another `$expand` value if it is not the `None` or `Links`.

For the 5 values of `$expand`(`None`, `Relations`, `Fields`, `Links`, `All`), only `None` and `Links` can work with `fields` successfully in API. This is a universal rule which apply to all APIs, including this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

---

Also, please use `$expand=Relations` in request body instead of in URI which shown as the document described. Here if you use it in URI, it will not be used by server script since the method that this API called does not has this parameter. Another API which can use $expand in the URI (**As normal, we would mention and show whether it can be used in URI in document**), the corresponding scripts have parameters can access these value which passed by URI.

So, here please use `$expand=Relations` in request body, then you would get the result with all fields and its all relations.

Comment: Hi, I have removed fields and added $expand =relations in URL. Now it is giving all fields, but relations are still missing

Comment: @JigarParekh Please use $expand=relations in request body which shown in the doc. Then you can see all fields and the relevant relations in the response.

Comment: @JigarParekh, Have update these content in the answer. Please refer to.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Are you saying that the only way to get relations section for a list of work items (or even a single work item) is if we also get the unabridged fields section alongside it?  This doesn't seem to make sense as a limitation, since the two sections are independent.  Especially for the bulk list call.  In our case we're mostly just interested in the relations for a long list of work items, and including the content of every possible field adds a lot of bloat.